# NtQueryInformationProcess and PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION result empty

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to enumerate process and get their SessionID back.
I wrote a function that consists of *NtQueryInformationProcess* (invoked dynamically) and I'm having some trouble with getting results from the PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION structure that im passing in(seems to be empty)

snapshot of from the debug:

The code from my function

```
enum_results enum_proc() {
    
    typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI* PNtQueryInformationProcess)(IN  HANDLE, IN  PROCESSINFOCLASS, OUT PVOID, IN ULONG, OUT PULONG);
    PNtQueryInformationProcess pNtQueryInformationProcess = (PNtQueryInformationProcess)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryInformationProcess");

    int pid;
    static int i;
    DWORD procs[1024], cbNeeded;
    if (!EnumProcesses(procs, sizeof(procs), &cbNeeded)) 
    {
        std::cout << "Couldnt retrive PS list";
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    int cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);
    for (i = 0;i <= cProcesses; i++)
    {

        int pid = (int)procs[i];
        if (pid > 0) {
            HANDLE current_proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, TRUE, procs[i]);
            PROCESSINFOCLASS info = {};
            auto pBasicInfo = new PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION();
            DWORD ret_length = 0;
            
            NTSTATUS stat = pNtQueryInformationProcess(current_proc, info, pBasicInfo, sizeof(pBasicInfo), (PULONG)ret_length);
            if (!stat)
            {
                cout << "couldnt invoke NtQueryInformationProcess..";
                exit(-1);
            };
            std::cout << procs[i];

            ULONG session = pBasicInfo->PebBaseAddress->SessionId;

            {
                enum_results ret_struct;
                ret_struct.pid = pid;
                ret_struct.process = current_proc;
                return ret_struct;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're reading your own PEB, not the target process's PEB.

Comment: `sizeof(pBasicInfo)` is wrong. `if (!stat)` is ok result, not error. not need `new PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION();`. not free memory. not need `GetProcAddress`..

Comment: also you need use `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` instead `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`, if you need only `SessionId` you can use `ProcessSessionInformation` or `ProcessIdToSessionId` and main - instead use `EnumProcesses` - use `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemProcessInformation` - it return session id

Comment: Thx  RbMm! , about the PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 
 I want to return a handle + a session id (later needs to be used for token duplication)

Comment: not use `EnumProcesses`. use `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemProcessInformation`

Comment: Semi-related: remove the (PULONG) cast. Don't use casts you don't understand just to shut up the compiler.